# cascaded op-amp and critical frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier

if we have two critical frequency in a cascaded op-amp which one we choose to be the total critical frequency ?[image]

i have the critical frequency  for the first amp and its gain also to the second amp .

then i want to find the voltage gain at a given frequency .

Comment: What are you trying to evaluate? It's unclear at the moment.

Comment: you see the question marks on the figure , i want to calculate the values of voltage gain at them . but the law of Aol need a  critical frequency . but i have two critical frequency at 3 and 1.5 which one i use to solve ?

Comment: You must show a circuit diagram. And - most important - the corresponding feedback circuitry. Stability problems arise only because of feedback !

Comment: look here is the full Q    https://scontent.fjrs3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/47035017_2134656396797975_626270686331011072_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_ht=scontent.fjrs3-1.fna&oh=0c496fd9d58e4b955ede8b4e66a36844&oe=5C72C48E

Comment: its an open-loop op-amp there is no feedback

Comment: well my question in other words is how to calculate the total critical frequency for two cascaded open-loop op-amp ? to use it in the open loop voltage gain law that you can see above to calculate the open loop voltage gain at any frequency that i want , i.e. i want the AV at f=4K Hz

Comment: Do you by any chance mean \$f_c\$, the corner or cutoff frequency?

Comment: https://scontent.fjrs3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/46857564_750077955354260_3705962039441620992_n.png?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.fjrs3-1.fna&oh=d4b10333a7ad1cfb8632c350f5722078&oe=5C6D18CD   here it is fc

Comment: and here there are 3 open loop op amps https://scontent.fjrs3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/46787912_266170814254503_4033397860618731520_n.png?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ht=scontent.fjrs3-1.fna&oh=cbd2aceafe6c75f11558241f17c6f6ba&oe=5C69C16B

Comment: Should be safe (no oscillation) to cascade an opamp and a BUFFER, such as LT1010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want the AV at f=4K Hz

At 1.5 kHz the open-loop gain starts to fall and, it falls at 20 dB per decade or 6 dB per octave. So, at 3 kHz (where the 2nd stage starts to become a factor), the open-loop gain has fallen by 6 dB because that is 1 octave higher than 1.5 kHz.

From this point it falls at 40 dB per decade (or 100 times for an increase in frequency of ten times). Given that 4 kHz is 1.333 times higher than 3 kHz, the fall in open-loop gain between 3 kHz and 4 kHz is 5 dB because: -

- Between 3 kHz and 30 kHz is a fall of 100 (40 dB) because 2 x 20 x \$\log(\frac{30}{3})\$ = 40 dB
- Between 3 kHz and 6 kHz is a fall of 4 and 2 x 20 x \$\log(\frac{6}{3})\$ = 12.04 dB
- The fall between 3 kHz and 4 kHz equates to 2 x 20 x \$\log(\frac{4}{3})\$ = 4.998 dB

So the fall from DC to 4 kHz is: -

- The fall to 3 kHz (6 dB) plus
- The fall from 3 kHz to 4 kHz (5 dB) = 11 dB.

Comment: thank u that's what i meant sorry because my English language is bad

Comment: Andy aka - I must admit that I am surprised. Did you understand the problem description? It seems so because you got points and an OK. In a graph the questioner shoes us (and speaks about) two "critical" frequencies....and lateron he speaks about two cascaded opamps...?? To me ...totally unclear.

Comment: @LvW I didn't follow him at first then a couple of hours later I saw the one line at the bottom of his question asking for Av at 4 kHz so I took a stab at it. Fortune favours the brave LOL.

Answer (score 0):

A very important recommendation: **Never** use two cascaded open loop opams. As soon as you will provide overall feedback (and, of course, you will do that for amplification purposes) - the whole stuff will oscillate (because - as mentioned in Andy akas comment - the magnitude slope is -40dB/dec).

If you need - for which purpose ever - such an arrangement, the second opamp must carefully (!) be quipped with local feedback.

Hence, it makers no sense to ask for the "critical frequency" (I suppose you mean: cut.off frequency?) of a circuitry that camnnot be used in practice.

Comment: but it is for a calculating purpose not a practical

Comment: Nevertheless, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Two IDENTICAL opamps in cascade? Each with a second-order gain function? And what is the final question?

Comment: i'm sorry am just a fresh student don't mind me .. i can't explain more than that , my language is bad ..